# Login Page in PHP is not working

Tags: php, mysql, html

```php
<body>
<?php
    session_start();

    function salt($pw) {
        $salt = "This comment should suffice as salt.";
        return sha1($salt.$pw);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'codekadiya', 'pass');
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo 'Connected successfully';
        mysql_close($link);

        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $password = salt($password);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query)== 0) {
            header("location:register.php");
            exit;
        }
        else {
            $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
            header("location: register.php");
        } 
    }
?>
</body>
```

I checked on my Connection. It says connection successful but I cant figure out what the other mistake are. Can someone guide me the mistake I have done? I can't find it.

Comment: Can you post the HTML and the table structure with the data types please? :)

Answer (score 8):

```
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
```

So you're closing the connection and then try to run queryes ? how should that work out ?

You should close the connection ( `mysql_close($link);` ) after you made you're query to the database ( meaning after `$query = mysql_query("SEL.....` )

Comment: even if i do that the $query dont take any rows. why is that. can you help me. its not directing to the register.php page

Comment: can someone guide me. i still couldnt find the problem yet. this wont direct to the register.php file. and it wont show the session username.

Comment: how do you store the password in the database ? do you convert it to `sha1($salt.$pw);` before adding it to the database ? basicly you change the password you're user passes , then you match it with the one you have in the database , but you need to have convert it first inside you're database .

Comment: i tried removing that password change and checked. its still not working. i still cant find the problem.

Comment: show us exactly what data you have in you're database , 1 row would be enough . we whont be able to find you're issue otherwize .

Comment: database name is marketwise, and the table name is test. it has 3 fields. Userid, username,password. and the data of the table is : userid: 1, username : admin, and password : pass

Comment: then remove `$password = salt($password);` and use admin and pass . first i would recomend you hardcode the username and pass in you're php file , and not retrive them with $_POST . make shure they look exactly like the ones you have in you're database . test it out . then go further and make shure you send the correct values with you're form .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really told us what doesn't work exactly, but it seems you are closing the MySQL link before the authentication query.

Answer (score 0):

i don't tend to use `isset` instead i just use if($_POST["something"]) that way i get more relevant errors

also - you're closing the $link before you use it - ???

Comment: how can you get more relevat errors with if($var) ? , isset() is there ( in php ) for a reason right ? shouldn't we use it ?

Comment: Some server setups require you to use isset otherwise they generate an error message specifying that the variable is undefined (or something  along those lines).

Comment: @Matt: yes ; @tekknolagi: you should definetly use isset , allways , i still can't understand why you're telling us you get more relevant errors , if a variable is not set you don't need to tell the user generating an error , but bypass it and exec other part of the code , or atleast display a nice standard message to the user "Opps there was an error! Pleas try again." as you don't whant users to know what's wrong with you're code

Comment: Your second point was the correct solution (but I think poelinca beat you to it :))